Type hint annotation for decorator around sync/async function
What is the correct way to specify a type annotation for a decorator that can be applied to both sync and async functions? I specify the type for the received function as type FuncType[**P, R] = AsyncFuncType[P, R] | SyncFuncType[P, R]. And one of AsyncFuncType or SyncFuncType for wrappers. But wrappers expect FuncType.
import asyncio
from functools import wraps
from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, Type


type AsyncFuncType[**P, R] = Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]
type SyncFuncType[**P, R] = Callable[P, R]
type FuncType[**P, R] = AsyncFuncType[P, R] | SyncFuncType[P, R]

def exc_wrapper[**P, R](
    exc_in: Type[Exception], exc_out: Type[Exception], *exc_args: Any, **exc_kwargs: Any
) -> Callable[[FuncType[P, R]], FuncType[P, R]]:
    def decorator(
        func: FuncType[P, R],
    ) -> FuncType[P, R]:
        @wraps(func)
        def sync_wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except exc_in:
                raise exc_out(*exc_args, **exc_kwargs)

        @wraps(func)
        async def async_wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Awaitable[R]:
            try:
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)
            except exc_in:
                raise exc_out(*exc_args, **exc_kwargs)

        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
            return async_wrapper
        else:
            return sync_wrapper

    return decorator

MyPy raises such errors:
src\core\utils\decorators.py:19: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Awaitable[R] | R", expected "R")  [return-value]
src\core\utils\decorators.py:26: error: Incompatible types in "await" (actual type "Awaitable[R] | R", expected type "Awaitable[Any]")  [misc]
src\core\utils\decorators.py:31: error: Incompatible return value type (got "_Wrapped[P, object, P, Coroutine[Any, Any, Awaitable[R]]]", expected "Callable[P, Awaitable[R]] | Callable[P, R]")  [return-value]

It works with only sync:
type FuncType[**P, R] = Callable[P, R]


def exc_wrapper[**P, R](
    exc_in: Type[Exception], exc_out: Type[Exception], *exc_args: Any, **exc_kwargs: Any
) -> Callable[[FuncType[P, R]], FuncType[P, R]]:
    def decorator(
        func: FuncType[P, R],
    ) -> FuncType[P, R]:
        @wraps(func)
        def sync_wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except exc_in:
                raise exc_out(*exc_args, **exc_kwargs)

        return sync_wrapper

    return decorator

or only async:
type FuncType[**P, R] = Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]


def exc_wrapper[**P, R](
    exc_in: Type[Exception], exc_out: Type[Exception], *exc_args: Any, **exc_kwargs: Any
) -> Callable[[FuncType[P, R]], FuncType[P, R]]:
    def decorator(
        func: FuncType[P, R],
    ) -> FuncType[P, R]:
        @wraps(func)
        async def async_wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
            try:
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)
            except exc_in:
                raise exc_out(*exc_args, **exc_kwargs)

        return async_wrapper

    return decorator

Both - not.

This has nothing to do with PEP 695 syntax. You want to return a generic function.

Possibly related: How to type annotate a multi-level decorator.

Thanks for your replies. I updated my question.
